# upload svg icon on local work but on server not work with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have an issue with my website when I add new icon with extension SVG on my local it work, then when I make an upload to server and try and a new icon with extension SVG too but it not work and return me with message `HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: Please show your error from log.

Comment: @VaheGalstyan here is my error log
ERROR - 2017-06-01 07:07:04 --> 404 Page Not Found: Products/order. But my icon directory it not store at their , I store Icon with another folder. why it return me Not Found: Products/order ?

Comment: maybe you should check your virtual host configurations, can you show local and server virtual host configurations.

Comment: I'm not sure it's virtual host on my local that I config:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin anana.dev
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/anana_soft"
    ServerName anana.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>`  

And on server I don't know how check it ?

Comment: Do you have access to server? Which environment you use on server(Linux or windows) ?

Comment: on server Operating System linux

Comment: check  /etc/apache2/sites-available folder, if you have access?

Comment: excuse me on server or local ?

Comment: on server, did you have admin access or maybe you use some hosting?

Comment: I'm access it cpanel

Comment: etc on root directory of file manager right ?

Comment: yes, contact with your hosting service to change configuration for root directory and root path